# Tideman problem from CS50 (not understanding the sort_pairs function)

Tags: c, function, struct, cs50

I'm currently trying to tackle the tideman problem from the cs50 course, and am trying to logically understand each and every step of it. In short it's code to work out the winner of an election. Rather than the most votes wins, it tackles polling by asking each voter to rank their preference of all candidates from most prefered to least prefered. And from there the code can make a more accurate and fair result. I'll link the assignment/ prompt link below.

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/3/tideman/

I'm stuck on the sort pairs function. The correct implementation is below in my code and is as far as I've gotten.

```
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = pair_count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser]) < (preferences[pairs[j + 1].winner][pairs[j + 1].loser]))
            {
                pair temp = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j + 1];
                pairs[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

For proper context once again you can see the link above, and later down I'll post my full code.

My problem is why is the preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] used, rather than simply preferences[i][j], the i and j in my mind would cover all indexes in the 2d preferences array, and be able to sort them by the size of each int found there. My mind breaks a little bit seeing the pair structs used in there. What am i not understanding here?

If you need more context let me know. Full code below, sorry for the book.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if (preferences[j][i] > preferences[i][j])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = pair_count - 1; i <= 0; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] <
             preferences[pairs[j + 1].winner][pairs[j + 1].loser])
             {
                pair temp = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j + 1];
                pairs[j + 1] = temp;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried reasoning everything out on paper, and this is the second time ive gone through this assignment in hope of logically understanding each step.

Comment: Avoid global variables and pass the relevant data to your sort function.

Comment: Use `qsort()`.  It's faster and reduces your sort problem to a comparison.

Comment: You should explain the problem you are asking for help with.  If it's the sort then the remaining code is irrelevant but you do need to explain how to sort it (not just reference a link).  Example input and matching output can be helpful.

Comment: *why is the preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] used* you are sorting pairs, not preferences. *rather than simply preferences[i][j]* Note that i is not used as an index in the correct version. Do you know how bubble sort works?

Comment: @AllanWind it is the comparison that creates the problem

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, that was my point.